# How to convert a string into an object in VBScript?

Tags: string, object, vbscript

```
X = "ABC"
```

I have to use this string as an object in an object hierarchy like

```
a.X.b.click
```

For the above statement to work, `X` i.e. string `"ABC"` should be converted into an object.
How can I do this?

Comment: Is the string an element name? (the value appears as name='ABC' on an HTML element in a web page)  An element ID?  An element *tag* name?  If it is any of those, there is a better way to do what you want. Please clarify your question with more context.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Dictionary object for your data structure.

```
Dim a
Dim X
X = "ABC"
Set a = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
a.Add("ABC", b)    ' Attaches the value b to the key "ABC" of the object a.
```

Now you can access b with either`a.Item("ABC")` or `a.Item(X)`

The Dictionary object on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242687